# How to sum similar pandas rows

Tags: python, pandas, sum

How to sum the pandas rows from `data_in` in order to get panda rows similar to the lines of `data_out`?

```
data_in = [
    { 'col-a':'a1', 'col-b':'b1', 'col-z':'z1', 'value':1},
    { 'col-a':'a1', 'col-b':'b1', 'col-z':'z1', 'value':2},
    { 'col-a':'a2', 'col-b':'b2', 'col-z':'z2', 'value':10},
    { 'col-a':'a2', 'col-b':'b2', 'col-z':'z2', 'value':20}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_in)

# which operation to apply on df to get rows like in data_out?
# ...

data_out = [
    { 'col-a':'a1', 'col-b':'b1', 'col-z':'z1', 'value':3},
    { 'col-a':'a2', 'col-b':'b2', 'col-z':'z2', 'value':30}
]
```

Comment: You provide input and output, but you don't seem to know how to get there? Obviously, this is a groupby.sum() operation, but do you know what to group on? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: My problem was to find the groupby.sum() operation, not to have the data_out python object. I gave data_out to express the resulting rows I wanted to obtain, given that I was not able to express my exact need in plain english. (With hindsight, I should have written data_out as an HTML table instead of python code to remove the ambiguity). Thanks

Comment: I don't think you got my point, but alright.

Answer (score 2):

This is an aggregating problem. You can use `.groupby` in pandas and while aggregating you can get the sum of these groups with `.value.sum()`

```
df_out = df.groupby(['col-a', 'col-b', 'col-z']).value.sum().reset_index()
print(df_out)

  col-a col-b col-z  value
0    a1    b1    z1      3
1    a2    b2    z2     30
```

Comment: I appreciate your desire to answer the question but this is a hit-or-miss answer. I hope your your sake it's the former.

Comment: Im sorry, not sure what you mean? Obviously im here to answer questions.

Comment: Refer to my comment under the question. Perhaps you would be grouping on one of the columns and calling first() on the rest of the string columns. That produces the same answer. Unfortunately since OP hasn't answered, can't be sure.

Comment: I see, sometimes I take 2 min between work to answer questions. So I did not see your comment. I will edit/remove my answer adjustingly to OP's comment. @coldspeed

Answer (score 1):

This is the line you are looking for:

```
df.groupby(["col-a", "col-b", "col-z"])["value"].sum()
```